# Magento 2.4.3 and Composer error messages for allure phpunit and ramsey uuid - Can't continue with update

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, phpunit, magento2.4.3

I'm getting some error messages from composer, when I try to upgrade from Magento 2.4.2 to Magento 2.4.3, and these are:

```
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3].
- allure-framework/allure-codeception[1.4.3, ..., 1.4.4] require allure-framework/allure-php-api ~1.1.8 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.8].
- allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.4.2 requires allure-framework/allure-php-api ~1.1.7 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.7, 1.1.8].
- allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.6, ..., 1.1.8] require ramsey/uuid ^3.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[3.0.0, ..., 3.9.4].
- allure-framework/allure-php-api 1.1.5 requires ramsey/uuid ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[3.0.0, ..., 3.9.4].
- Only one of these can be installed: rhumsaa/uuid[2.7.0, ..., 2.8.2], ramsey/uuid[3.0.0, ..., 3.9.4, 4.0.0, ..., 4.2.1]. ramsey/uuid replaces rhumsaa/uuid and thus cannot coexist with it.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 requires ramsey/uuid ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[4.1.0, 4.1.1].
- Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid[4.1.1] | install one of magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.6.0, 3.6.1] (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.6.0 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.6.1 (conflict analysis result)
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.6.1].
- Root composer.json requires allure-framework/allure-phpunit ~1.2.0 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.2.0, ..., 1.2.4].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.0, ..., 1.3.1].
- allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.4.5 requires allure-framework/allure-php-api ~1.2.1 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.2.1].
- Conclusion: install one of magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.6.0, 3.6.1], allure-framework/allure-codeception[1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5] (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.2.1] | install one of allure-framework/allure-php-api[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.8] (conflict analysis result)
```

To my knowledge, I haven't changed anything. Last upgrade went fine (from 2.4.2 to 2.4.2-p1).
This is my *composer.json* file content:

```
"require": {
    "fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2": "^8.0",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
    "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
    "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
},
```

I have no idea how to continue.
Thank you,

Comment: You can check this link regarding this: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Problem-upgrading-Magento-2-4-2-p1-to-2-4-3/m-p/480185#M18307

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if you want any details summarized further. This should get you where you want, we do upgrades all the time at my job. Key piece of information to take-away is keeping dependencies in composer.json up-do-date with latest from upgrades, even the require-dev deps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Magento 2.4.3 composer.json

Taking a look at the 2.4.3 codebase, it looks like the `composer.json` has newer `require-dev` dependencies than what you have posted.

Typically when doing upgrades, among other things, you want to compare dependencies in the old/new `composer.json` files. It would be worth matching up your `composer.json` with the updated `require-dev` dependencies listed below.

**Mutiple Commands:**

```
composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.4
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.18.1
composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan:^0.12.77
composer require --dev sebastian/phpcpd:^6.0.3
composer require --dev symfony/finder:^5.2
```

**Single Command:**

This is in case composer fails to update packages one at a time.

```
composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.4 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.18.1 phpstan/phpstan:^0.12.77 sebastian/phpcpd:^6.0.3 symfony/finder:^5.2
```

**Manual Update:**

This is in case composer fails to update packages one at a time or all at once with the single command.

1. Manually edit `composer.json`, updating the versions of mentioned require-dev packages.
2. Save `composer.json`
3. Run `composer update` (you may see other packages get updated)

[Magento 2.4.3 - composer.json](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.3/composer.json#L110-L125)

```json
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
```

#### Allure Git Repository Renamed

Recently, Allure had renamed their git repo causing failures when composer tries to download the `allure-framework/allure-php-api` package. There is an open ticket on Magento about it:

[Magento2 github issues - Changed repository name of one of the composer.lock included packages](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33920)

The way we fixed was to update the package to get the new repo url:

```
composer clear-cache
composer update allure-framework/allure-php-api
```

That should kick off the following change to `composer.lock`:

[image: composer.lock change]

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.4.3 requires composer 2.
If you use root update plugin, it won't work since it supports only composer 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of composer than you may reverse to old version 1.x of composer than it may work **if you are facing above mentioned error only**